# cannot reindex duplicate axis

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to merge multiple csv files in a folder.

They look like this (there are more than two df's in actuality):

df1

```
LCC  acres
2    10
3    20
4    40
5    5
```

df2

```
LCC  acres_2
2    4
3    2
4    40
5    6
6    7
```

I want to put all the dataframes into one list, and then merge them with reduce.  To do this they need to have the same index.

I am trying this code:

```
combined = []
reindex = [2,3,4,5,6]

folder = r'C:\path_to_files'

for f in os.listdir(folder):

    #read each file
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder,f))

    #check for duplicates - returns empty lists
    print df[df.index.duplicated()]

    #reindex
    df.set_index([df.columns[0]], inplace=True)
    df=df.reindex(reindex, fill_value=0)

    #append
    combined.append(df)


#merge on 'LCC' column
final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['LCC'], how='outer'), combined)
```

but this still returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-45f925f6d48d>", line 9, in <module>
    df=df.reindex(reindex, fill_value=0)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2741, in reindex
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2229, in reindex
    fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2687, in _reindex_axes
    fill_value, limit, tolerance)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2698, in _reindex_index
    allow_dups=False)

File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2341, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3586, in reindex_indexer
    self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2293, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem you need check duplicates of index after setting first column to index.

```
#set index by first column
df.set_index([df.columns[0]], inplace=True)

#check for duplicates - returns NO empty lists
print df[df.index.duplicated()]

#reindex
df=df.reindex(reindex, fill_value=0)
```

Or check duplicates in first column instead index, also parameter `keep=False` return all duplicates (if necessary):

```
#check duplicates in first column
print df[df.iloc[:, 0].duplicated(keep=False)]

#set index + reindex
df.set_index([df.columns[0]], inplace=True)
df=df.reindex(reindex, fill_value=0)
```